# Load Imagesource into Control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, controls

I need an instance of System.Windows.Controls.Control which displays an image. 
But all i have is an imagesource.

I can use

```
var image = new Image();
image.Source = imageSource;
```

but, besides Image is in the Controls namespace, it is itself not derived from Control.

Is there an easy way to get the Imagesource programmatically into a control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in a ContentControl.

```
ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
cc.Content = image;
```

But I'm really curious why you need a Control.

Comment: it's as easy as that :) thank you! has to be a control, because my colleagues love controls, but i just created an imagesource (which to me is the way to represent an image)... but i'm new to WPF, so i do not have much to say